# Read data from plist under a specific condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have a .plist in my Xcode project like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Steve</key>
    <dict>
        <key>married</key>
        <true/>
        <key>website</key>
        <string>http://www.abc.com</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Bill</key>
    <dict>
        <key>website</key>
        <string>http://www.cab.com</string>
        <key>married</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

so now I only wanna read the website if married is true. The plist above is only an example I know it makes no sense. Can you please help me ? :)
Edit I now do it like this:

```
if ([[dict objectForKey:@"married"] boolValue]) {
        NSLog(@"(Y)");
    }
```

But if I do that for every dict it's much work and I think I could do it easier but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand your question clearly but as per my understanding i think your looking to implement a for each loop, so here is how you can go through the entire plist at once:

```
NSMutableArray *arryaOfBools =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];//To keep the values if you wnat
NSDictionary *dictioanry =  [[NSDictionary alloc] init];// initialize your plist
// this for each will traverse through every dictionary present in the plist
for(NSDictionary * dict in dictioanry ){
 /// you can do anything here as per your requirements 
 [arryaOfBools addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"married"]];
}
```

Hope this answers your question..

EDIT:

Here is the solution to your code

```
NSDictionary *senderDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePathforPlsit];

for(NSString *keyValue in senderDictionary){
    [[senderDictionary valueForKey:keyValue] valueForKey:@"shortcut"];
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm silly (I think so I'm new at xcode) but that doesn't work for me. The "dictionary" and the "arrayofBools" are still empty?
You are right, I want to scan the whole plist but in a Dictionary only the entries with "married = true" should return.

Comment: Can you post the entire code where you are trying to achieve this? may be can help you!

Comment: `NSDictionary *senderDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];  
NSLog(@"%@",senderDictionary);  
//NSDictionary *antenne = senderDictionary[@"Antenne Bayern"];  
    //NSLog(@"%@",antenne);  
    NSMutableArray *arrayofBools = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];  
    for(senderDictionary in dictionary) {  
        [arrayofBools addObject:[senderDictionary objectForKey:@"shortcut"]];  
    }`

Comment: here it is. Please help me

Comment: Hey thanks but I dont get it now in the log it prints this:
2014-03-27 22:37:56.710 SmaartRadio[4733:303] -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x618000030360

Comment: i'm really sorry, replace `objectForKey` with `valueForKey`

Comment: Thanks that you help me out :) but now there is a new error in the log: 2014-03-27 22:43:22.835 SmaartRadio[4758:303] [<__NSCFString 0x6080000344a0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key shortcut.

Comment: can you also share your plist file.. will give you the exact working code.. you have not parsed your plist file correctly, that is why you are getting this error.

Comment: here it is thanks again :)  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>Antenne Bayern</key>
 <dict>
  <key>shortcut</key>
  <true/>
  <key>url</key>
  <string>http://www.antenne.de/webradio/antenne-aac.pls</string>
 </dict>
 <key>Technobase.fm</key>
 <dict>
  <key>url</key>
  <string>http://listen.technobase.fm/tunein-aacplus-pls</string>
  <key>shortcut</key>
  <false/>
 </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
`

Comment: Thanks for your help now it displays in KeyValue all entries but I only want that entries with shortcut = 1 are displayed. Now the log is: 2014-03-28 18:02:25.061 SmaartRadio[2045:303] Antenne Bayern
2014-03-28 18:02:25.061 SmaartRadio[2045:303] Technobase.fm